Next.js 14: Cache not invalidating properly despite using revalidateTag
I have a Next.js 14 app that displays match statistics. When a specific condition is met, I need to invalidate the cache to fetch fresh data.
The problem I'm facing is no matter I'm revalidating the tags I'm still getting the stale  data from cache.
The issue occurs in local environment and also in Production.
Current Implementation
My page.tsx fetches match info and statistics. If exp param is present and is ==== '123ABC' I do revalidate tags for both requests and redirect with the intention of fetching the fresh data. It's supposed that once the redirection is performed the exp param is not present anymore so the flow continues as usual.
const Page = async ({ params, searchParams }: Props) => {
  const last = searchParams?.last || '5';
  const exp = searchParams?.exp;

  if (exp === '123ABC') {
    revalidateTag('statistics');
    revalidateTag('matchById');
    redirect(`/match/${params.id}?last=${last}`);
  }

  // Main data fetching
  const data = await getMatchInfo({ matchId: params.id });
  const stats = await getStatistics({
    homeTeamId: String(data.teams.home.id),
    awayTeamId: String(data.teams.away.id),
    leagueId: data.league.id,
    last,
    timezone: getTimezone(),
  });

  // ... rest of the component

  return <StatsComponent data={data} stats={stats}/>

}

These are the requests: As you can see I'm using the correct tags
export const getMatchInfo = async ({
  matchId,
  timezone,
}: {
  matchId: string | number;
  timezone?: string;
}): Promise<Match> => {
  try {
    const finalTimezone = timezone || process.env.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': `${process.env.API_KEY}`,
      },
      next: {
        revalidate: parseInt(process.env.MATCH_INFO || '1500', 10),
        tags: ['matchById'],
      },
    };

    const finalUrl = `${process.env.API_URL}/matches?matchId=${matchId}&timezone=${finalTimezone}`;
    const res = await fetch(finalUrl, requestOptions);

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }

    const parsedResponse = await res.json();
    return parsedResponse.payload.data[0];
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
};


export const getStatistics = async ({
    homeTeamId,
    awayTeamId,
    leagueId,
    last,
    timezone: getTimezone(),
  }) => {
  try {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': `${process.env.API_KEY}`,
      },
      next: {
        revalidate: parseInt(process.env.STATISTICS_TTL || '3600', 10),
        tags: ['statistics'],
      },
    };

    const finalUrl = `${process.env.API_URL}/statistics?homeTeamId=${homeTeamId}&awayTeamId=${awayTeamId}&leagueId=${leagueId}&last=${last}&timezone=${timezone}`;
    const res = await fetch(finalUrl, requestOptions);

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }

    const parsedResponse = await res.json();
    return parsedResponse.payload.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
};

Versions
    "next": "^14.2.13",
    "react": "18.2.0",

